# How to use an IENumerable collection as model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, syntax, umbraco

I am using a partial view where I would like to use a collection of a custom model:

`@model IENumerable<MyProject.Models.Currency>`

This works but I would also like to use the built-in helpers etc from Umbraco, and the documentation says I have to inherit the `UmbracoViewPage` like so:

`@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<MyProject.Models.Currency>`

This is however not a IENumerable anymore. Anyone knows the syntax to combine the `IENumerable` and `@inherits` syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry - easy one:

`@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<IENumerable<MyProject.Models.Currency>>`

Hope it helps someone.